# transfer android and ios application from developer account to another one

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

hope you all fine

My problem is somecompany made an application for me for android and ios
and now I want to transfer these apps to my accounts
the problem is these accounts have GCM. so I want to keep these IDs 
they told me that they will give me the GCM IDs database
and I have to make a script to handle the send of notification
But I know that when you register a new device with gcm you have to pass the
project ID.. that you made on your google account
and I have a different project ID than they have. 
so the register of any device will vary .. 
the new devices will work without any problem

but my problem is with the old devices!!
when I send a notification with the Device ID and the access token
the token is for another project ID that this Device ID generated to !!
so I think it will fail and not send any notification for old clients ..
its true ???

if its true please may you give me the correct way to transfer the app with GCM project or clients

thank you.

Comment: If it's an option, you can transfer over the project too. The owner can [manage members](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/access#usersproject) for a project.